# Duplicates in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose you have a set L={l1,l2,l3,l4,...,ln} where it is possible for 2 or more ls to be equal thus creating duplicate within the set,is it possible to have such a set and if so can you count the number of terms n including the duplicates(i want the cardinality of L to be n but i want the duplicate terms to count.

example: L={1,1,2} ,with what i found online cardinality of L=2,is it possible to make it = 3?

Comment: Let's rather call it a *sequence* or *tuple* of elements, then repetition (and the order) is understood. There are also so called *multisets*.

Comment: what would be the best term to define a group of elements where the order matters and two or more same elements count as different elements?

Comment: A sequence. ${{{}}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets do not contain duplicates.  Your example $L = \{1,1,2\}$ is not a set.

For a generalization of sets to a collection that permits duplicates, see [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Comment: I think this is the closest to what OP is really asking for...

Answer (score 0):

In order to talk about cardinality, you need to talk about bijections. To make the cardinal of that "set" equal to 3, you would have to have two distinct images for 1, this is of course absurd by the definition of a function.